# How to divide data into 10 folds and save in an array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a data set which I don't know the number of records in it.
I want to implement cross validation manually, make a long story short I want to divide my data to 10 folds and save each fold in an array or a list. 
what should I do?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to divide a data set, perhaps a list, into 10-equal sublists?

Comment: @Miket25 yes. that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
length = int(len(data)/10) #length of each fold
folds = []
for i in range(9):
    folds += [data[i*length:(i+1)*length]]
folds += [data[9*length:len(data)]]
```

To get a list of lists containing 1/10th of the array or list, with the last containing the remainder.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data set is a numpy array `data_set`, where the columns are the training features, and the rows `num_rows` are the different training instances (samples), you can use:

```
import numpy as np

N_folds = 10
# Determine the correct indices to split the data.
limits = np.linspace(0, num_rows+1, N_fold+1, dtype=int)

for i in range(len(limits) - 1):
    # Split the data at the correct indices and save it.
    np.save('arr_{}.npy'.format(i), data_set[limits[i] : limits[i+1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
def array_split(arr, folds):
    kcount = int(len(arr)/folds)
    count = 0
    vals = []
    for i in range(1, folds+1):
        kcount = kcount*(i)
        fold = arr[count:kcount]
        count = kcount
        vals.append(fold)
    return vals
```